# How to erase a read character while reading using getch()

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a string using getch() in a loop. When I press backspace it reads backspace as a character. So when I press backspace I need to erase the read character. I need to erase from screen.

```
while((c=getch())!=13)
{
    if(c==8)
    {
        i=i-1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("*");
        str[i]=c;
        i++;
    }
}
str[i]='\0';
```

Comment: Reading into a char from console and making changes to the console itself is different. you can achive this by making low level system calls , is that what you want . understand about terminal and how you read and write from/to it.

Comment: do not use ascii code when it is know in c, for instance 13 is \r ... and I think you want to test the end of the line, so \n. But first are you sure your input is not in blocking mode and you will read immediately the characters rather than after the full line including \n was entered ? Out of that just search on overflow and your problem was asked lot of times already

Comment: what are you trying to do ? to enter a password (I say because of the print `'*'`). Do you have an echo when a character is read by _getch()_ ? if yes you need to go back also to replace by `'*'` etc

Comment: `i=i-1;` is not valid when the first read character is a backspace, you need to test the value of i before

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to read a password

```
char str[100];
int c;
int i=0;

while((c=getch())!='\r')
{
  if(c!='\b')
  {
    printf("*"); // putchar not ok with MSVC ?
    str[i++]=c;
  }
  else if (i != 0) {
    printf("\b"); // or putchar
    i -= 1;
  }
}
str[i]='\0';
printf("str=%s\n", str);
```

that code miss to check the password is not longer than 99 characters ...

Comment: I don't have a windows system to try this on but I'd expect to have to write "backspace-space-backspace" to delete a visible character on the console